# Modify more than one data-type field in a single query in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to change a lot of data-type fields in MySQL database table. The desired data-type of the fields is the same `INTEGER` for all the fields (they are currently most `VARCHAR`).

This query works fine:

`ALTER TABLE heights MODIFY height1 INTEGER;`

The problemas is that my `heights` table has more tha 100 fields (height1, heightProm, heightMax, etc.), and I need to change the type of all these fields to `INTEGER`.

I try:
`ALTER TABLE heights MODIFY height1 INTEGER, height2 INTEGER, height3 INTEGER;` but doesn't work (MySQL returns `You have an error in your SQL syntax;`).

Any way to convert all in the same query?

Comment: "but doesn't work." --- what does it mean?

Comment: It's not. What actual error?

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near height2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [syntax for `ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) is:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
[alter spec 1],
[alter spec 2], ...
```

And in your case, that `alter spec` is `MODIFY column dataType`, so you need to write something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE heights
MODIFY height1 INTEGER,
MODIFY height2 INTEGER, ....
```

Answer (score 3):

`MODIFY` is the part of alteration that must be repeated

```
ALTER TABLE heights MODIFY height1 INTEGER,
                    MODIFY height2 INTEGER,
                    MODIFY height3 INTEGER;
```

References:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html

Comment: Wow, we answered at the exact same time :)

Comment: @BobM yep, I was faster though. Mutual +1 ;-P

Comment: We all three answered at the same time ;)

Comment: Actually you were 20 seconds late! But I +1d you anyway ;P

Comment: @BobM what matters is that Barranka got the checkmark finally :-D

Comment: @BobM Don't blame the typing speed... blame the internet connection ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
ALTER TABLE heights MODIFY height1 INTEGER, MODIFY height2 INTEGER, MODIFY height3 INTEGER;
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html